# Looking for a short story about a person who hacked an astronaut competition

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember (vaguely) a SciFi short story, in an anthology book, probably written in the 1950s or 1960s about an organization that was holding a competition for staff/astronauts.

The main plot was that the protagonist, and possibly his friends, instead of doing the competition honestly, hacked their way into the computer systems, giving themselves high marks for things they hadn't actually done.

Towards the end of the story they got found out and, under pursuit, the hero boldly jumped into a storage locker saying "well, I'll see you later!". The guards pursuing him said "you would think he had taken the next freighter to Mars!".

Our hero found an exit at the back of the locker into an air-conditioning duct, and escaped. He was eventually captured, and informed that he had passed the test, as they were looking for people with imagination and ingenuity.

Anyone know the author/title and maybe the anthology it was published in?

Comment: What about this story is sci-fi or fantasy? As described it seems to be a mundane thriller about a hacker

Comment: @Valorum - Ah, yes, I also take freighters to Mars frequently.

Comment: @Adamant - Maybe it's just an expression though. Are there *literally* freighters to Mars in the story?

Comment: @Valorum It's been about 30 or 40 years. I don't recall the exact sentence. However I thought it was SciFi because most of my reading at the time was SciFi and not fantasy.